# Quart JSON encoding

Tags: python, quart

as first time `Quart` user, I struggle defining json encoder / decoder.
I have nested objects like this:

```
class ObjA:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.__color = color

class Color:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.t = t
```

Is it possible to define encoder/decoder foreach Class and let quart handle the rest ?

Comment: In my answer I've assumed you just want to use the `jsonify` function to return json. If you want to accept json, or something else (a reason to need a decoder) could you say what the use case is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the `jsonify` function, you can do this by defining a custom JSONEncoder as so,

```
from quart.json import JSONEncoder

class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Color):
            return obj.t
        elif isinstance(obj, ObjA):
            return {
                'name': obj.name,
                '_color': self.default(obj._color),
            }
        else:
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

app = Quart(__name__)
app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder
```

Note I've changed the `__color` variable to `_color` to avoid issues with name mangling.

Answer (score 0):

In your class define a method as following:

```
class MessageTextDto:
"""MessageTextDto model"""

def __init__(self, message_id: int, text: str, date: datetime):
    self.message_id = message_id
    self.text = text
    self.date = date

def serialize(self):
    return {
        "message_id": self.message_id,
        "text": self.text,
        "date": self.date.isoformat()
    }
```

Then when you have to encode your object to json, call this method if you want use jsonify:

```
obj = MessageTextDto()
obj.message_id = 1
obj.text = "a"
obj.date = datetime.now()
return jsonify(obj.serialize())
```

Or even:

```
obj = MessageTextDto()
obj.message_id = 1
obj.text = "a"
obj.date = datetime.now()
return json.dumps(obj.serialize())
```